# Android Time Picker example in the Android developer guide

Tags: android, timepicker

This link shows how to create a Time Picker using DialogFragment
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

Is it possible that there is a typo in the example shown? When I copy and paste the example in a new class in Eclipse, it says that **static** is an illegal modifier. What am I doing wrong?
This is what I have in Eclipse:

```
package com.example.symptommanagement;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }

}
```

By the way, if I delete the **static** modifier, the code works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illegal modifier error for static class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831791/illegal-modifier-error-for-static-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created a simple, seperated class for the Fragment. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047870/2891426) SO question:

> Fragments have to be either regular Java classes or static inner classes, and they need to have a public zero-argument constructor.

I think, all the examples on the Google Developer site written to be static inner classes.

In Java only the nested classes can be `static` classes, see: [Why are you not able to declare a class as static in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3584113/2891426)

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the case. Thanks!